# AppleScript script command implementation

Tags: cocoa, applescript

I'm trying to implement a trivial script command, byt have no success..
My sdef file

```
...
<class name="image" plural="images" code="imag" description="Image class">
    <cocoa class="MyImage" />
    <property name="width" code="wdth" type="real" access="r" description="The width of the image."/>
    <property name="height" code="hght" type="real" access="r" description="The height of the image."/>
    <responds-to name="rotate">
        <cocoa method="scriptingRotate:"/>
    </responds-to>
</class>
<command name="rotate" code="frwkrota" description="Rotate the image.">
    <direct-parameter type="image"/>
    <parameter name="by" code="by  " type="real" description="Degrees to rotate.">
        <cocoa key="angle"/>
    </parameter>
</command>
...
```

My dictionary is ok: image responds to rotate and so on..
But

```
tell application "MyApp"
    rotate image 1 by 1
end tell
```

says that: "Expected end of line but found class name." Where is the mistake?

`get image 1` works normally (MyImage have objectSpecifier).

SOLVED

Seems like it was a bug with ScriptEditor..

Restarting ScriptEditor solved the problem.